# CSS/less from header file only works on the index page

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4, less, processwire

Welcome to my first post. I've searched stackoverflow for an hour to find the awnser I need, but without succes.

I'm currently creating my own website to test php with processwire and bootstrap. I am quite new to programming in general, but I have only three weeks of experience with php/processwire. I'm using this because I got an internship where they use it and I would like to create my own project in my spare time to speed up the learning proces.

---

I'm using a separate header/footer file that I import in each template. I notice that my CSS that is imported in the header file only works on my home.php template and not on my other ones. The html/php from header works fine, it's just the css that isn't working.

My files:

- site
- assets

  - less

    - styles.less
- templates

  - _includes

    - _head.php
    - _foot.php
  - home.php
  - basic-page.php

---

I tried:

- Change to css instead of less
- Changing css import with ../ instead of site/
- Copying all content of home.php into basic-page.php to see if the
  problem was in the template.

---

### part of header:

```
    <?php namespace ProcessWire; ?>
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      
      <title><?php echo $page->title; ?></title>
      <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $page->summary; ?>" />
      <!-- MDB icon -->
      <!--  <link rel="icon" href="img/mdb-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">  -->
          
    
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
      <!-- Google Fonts Roboto -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lusitana:400,700|Quattrocento:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/assets/css/bootstrap/mdb.min.css" />
      <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/assets/less/styles.less" />
      
    
    
    </head>

<body>
```

### part of footer

```
    </footer>
    <!--/.Footer-->
    
    
    <!-- End your project here-->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    

    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site/assets/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Your custom scripts (optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site/assets/js/main.js" ></script>

    <!-- Import less file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/site/assets/js/less.js" ></script>
    
    
    
    

</body>
</html>
```

### template home.php

```
<?php include('./_includes/_head.php'); // include header markup ?>

    <main>
        
      
        <!--Main layout-->
        <div class="container">
            <!--First row-->
    
            <!--/.First row-->
      
            <hr class="extra-margins">
      
            <!--Second row-->
            <div class="row">
                

                    <!--Test columnn-->
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <!--Card-->
                        <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                            <!--Card image-->
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(3).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                            <!--Card content-->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <!--Title-->
                                <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                                <!--Text-->
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.Card-->
                    </div>

                    <!--Test columnn-->
                
                <!--First columnn-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <!--Card image-->
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(3).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->
                </div>
                <!--First columnn-->
      
                <!--Second columnn-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                        <!--Card image-->
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(1).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->
                </div>
                <!--Second columnn-->
      
                <!--Third columnn-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                        <!--Card image-->
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(4).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      
                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->
                </div>
                <!--Third columnn-->
                    
            </div>
            <!--/.Second row-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Main layout-->
      
    </main> 
    

<?php include('./_includes/_foot.php'); // include footer markup ?>
```

### template basic-page.php

```
<?php include('./_includes/_head.php'); // include header markup ?>
    
    <main>
        
      
        <!--Main layout-->
        <div class="container">
            <!--First row-->
    
            <!--/.First row-->
      
            <hr class="extra-margins">
      
            <!--Second row-->
            <div class="row">
                
    
                    <!--Test columnn-->
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <!--Card-->
                        <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                            <!--Card image-->
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(3).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                            <!--Card content-->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <!--Title-->
                                <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                                <!--Text-->
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.Card-->
                    </div>
    
                    <!--Test columnn-->
                
                <!--First columnn-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <!--Card image-->
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(3).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->
                </div>
                <!--First columnn-->
      
                <!--Second columnn-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                        <!--Card image-->
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(1).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->
                </div>
                <!--Second columnn-->
      
                <!--Third columnn-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                        <!--Card image-->
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Architecture/4-col/img%20(4).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      
                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">This is title</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->
                </div>
                <!--Third columnn-->
                    
            </div>
            <!--/.Second row-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Main layout-->
      
    </main> 


<?php include('./_includes/_foot.php'); // include footer markup ?>
```

### Thank you for taking the time to read this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
<?php namespace ProcessWire; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      
      <title><?php echo $page->title; ?></title>
      <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $page->summary; ?>" />
      <!-- MDB icon -->
      <!--  <link rel="icon" href="img/mdb-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">  -->
          
    
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
      <!-- Google Fonts Roboto -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lusitana:400,700|Quattrocento:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/assets/css/bootstrap/mdb.min.css" />
      <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/assets/less/styles.less" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/assets/less/styles.less" />
```

to

```
<?php include 'site/assets/less/styles.less'; ?>
```

that should work, and make sure you have

```
<?php include '/path/to/header.php'; ?>
```

in all of your files as well that works for me at least.

Comment: This worked, I'm quite stunned atm. Mainly because the link method does seem to work on another project. Maybe there's a plugin in play or something. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.